# Finding values of patterns in an array

Tags: python

If I have an array:

```
 A = [1,3,4,5]
```

And a dictionary that corresponds with pattern types, such that pattern type 0 was position 0 of the array, and pattern type 5 was index 0, index 3 of the array:

```
 patterrnDict = {1:[0],5:[0,3]}
```

Now say for pattern type 5, I only care about the value, so while patternDict[5] would return 1,5, I really want the value of 1+5, so I want an output of 6. How would I achieve this?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having difficulty understanding what you are asking.

Comment: `sum(A[i] for i in patterrnDict[5])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
>>> sum(A[index] for index in patternDict[5])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, map(A.__getitem__, pd[5]))
```

certainly, you can write a function to do this.